# Disable PHP stack traces in Apache logs?

Tags: php, security, apache-2.4

I've run across an in-house PHP application which occasionally crashes during user authentication and dumps a stacktrace into */var/log/apache2/*. Problem is it logs the username and pass in cleartext.

```
PHP Fatal error...Stack trace:...ldapauthenticated('bobuser', 'secrit123')...
```

I've run across a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766931/disable-php-stack-trace) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003602/how-do-i-disable-stack-traces-for-php) on various stack* forums about disabling the stack traces in *.htaccess* or with a line of code in the PHP app itself however there seem to be varying degrees of success with these methods and I'd rather just disable the lot of it site-wide instead of editing a jazillion PHP code files.

I thought I'd poke around in `/etc/php/` for an obvious setting somehow but there are myriad files and several directories there (`7.0/ir, 7.0/cli, 7.0/cli/conf.d, 7.0/apache2/conf.d/,...`) and no idea which file takes precedence over the other. I did find a `log_errors` setting which looked promising in `7.0/apache2/php.ini` however the comment there says the default is `off`. Obviously either not working or the wrong config item.

Anyone know of a way to disable PHP stacktraces site wide?

Comment: What Linux distribution is it? What PHP version? Where did you obtain it?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 running bundled PHP 7.0 (not the ondrej repo)

Comment: Your application also needs an exception handler to not die with a trace, at least when there is a credential on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
```

in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini